# Angular how to test outgoing parameter?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

i am trying to test a method from my service. unfortunately i don't get any parameters in the testrequest object. i am trying to log 'username' and 'password'. It comes only 'null' as value. When I try to log the keys I get an empty array. I hope someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong

here is my testmethod:

```
it('should return user session', () => {
const username = 'mock@test.de';
const password = '23743423hUHVTCFTZE';

authService.signIn(username, password)
  .subscribe(userSession => {
    expect(userSession).toBeTruthy();
    expect(userSession.status).toBe(200);
    expect(userSession.body).toEqual(MOCK_USER_SESSION);
  });

const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(
  req => req.url ==`${environment.baseUrl}/sales/authenticate`);

expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
console.log('username:' + req.request.params.get('username'));
console.log('password:' + req.request.params.get('password'));
console.log('keys:' + req.request.params.keys());

req.flush(MOCK_USER_SESSION);
```

})

and here is my method i want to test:

```
signIn(username: string, password: string): Observable<HttpResponse<AuthenticationResponse>> {
    return this.http.post<AuthenticationResponse>(`${environment.baseUrl}${this.urlAuthenticate}`,
      {username: username, password: password},
      {observe: 'response'});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
expect(req.request.body.username).toEqual(username);
expect(req.request.body.password).toEqual(password);
```